# Setting up on Ubuntu 14.04, trusty

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, ppa

This is my current version of Ubuntu:

```
root@vps132318:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I know this question has been asked several times and I checked them all. For all of their cases, the problem was their current version of Ubuntu. Although I use the 14.04 version, and when I type

```
root@ssss:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kurento/kurento
kurento/kurento
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --
homedir /tmp/tmp.mvnesaHwib --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --
keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --
keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys

root@ssss:~# sudo apt-get update
W: Failed to fetch      
http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

root@ssss:~# sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kurento-media-server
```

---

The two solutions I found around were:

1. add-key one; but for their cases, the `--recv-keys` part was giving them a key, so they were adding the key. Mine doesn't. Missing key is not given to me.
2. `sudo update apt-get`, however, no luck for me again.
3. I have also tried to `apt-upgrade`, no luck eithe.
4. Lastly, I tried clearing `trusted.gpg.d` directory, but no luck again.
5. [Automatically importing all missing GPG keys.](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html) But when I try `sudo launchpad-getkeys`, this is what I get:

   ```
   Trying to import all the missing keys
   Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.emB6wtnXhs --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy= --recv-keys
   Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.8jUZsvy2cn --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy= --recv-keys
   Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.1pWJuVDYhk --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy= --recv-keys
   Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.db8jIl1DVT --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy= --recv-keys
   Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.VpS5aiBz52 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy= --recv-keys

   launchpad-getkeys has finished importing all missing GPG keys. Try running sudo apt-get update - you shouldn't see any key  errors any more.
   .............................................................
   Note that launchpad-getkeys imports missing GPG keys but does not fix broken keys.
   ```

   And then `sudo apt-get update`:

   ```
   Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main amd64 Packages             
   404  Not Found
   Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main i386 Packages
   404  Not Found
   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Translation-en_GB
   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Translation-en
   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Translation-en_GB
   Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Translation-en
   W: Failed to fetch      
   http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
   W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
   ```

---

Am I missing out something or doing something wrong?

Comment: The issue is that it's looking for a Lucid Lynx folder to find the packages for the kurento ppa. Problem is, that folder doesn't exist (and you don't want to use it anyway). Try doing `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` followed by `sudo ppa-purge ppa:kurento/kurento` followed by reinstalling it with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kurento/kurento`

Comment: I did what you said. Here are the terminal console logs: 1) `sudo apt-get-install ppa-purge` . I ended up with bunch of errors. 2) `sudo ppa-purge ppa:kurento/kurento` . [Here is the console log...](https://shrib.com/gLYKnLBY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, there is a 10.04 PPA in your sources. Look closely at the erring URL:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

`lucid` is 10.04.

It's possible you have two entries of that PPA, one for 14.04, which you added just now, and one for 10.04, probably a hangover of some upgrade. Do `grep lucid /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`, find the offending entries and delete them.